# shapeless record get value by Symbol

Tags: scala, shapeless

Trying to extract a field value but it doesn't work when called with a Symbol

```
case class Dog(name: String, age: Int)
val dog = Dog("rocky", 5)
val repr = LabelledGeneric[Dog].to(dog)
val sy = 'name
repr.get(sy)
```

but works if I do

```
repr.get('name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first example works because the macro expansion actually converts the `Symbol` instance to a `Witness` instance (using `Witness.mkWitness`) which is actually what `repr.get` is expecting.

In order to make this work we need to create an instance of the `Witness` we want explicitly:

```
import shapeless.{LabelledGeneric, Witness}

case class Dog(name: String, age: Int)
val dog = Dog("rocky", 5)

val repr = LabelledGeneric[Dog].to(dog)
val nameWitn = Witness('name)
repr.get(nameWitn)
```

Comment: Oh yes, I did that but what about if I need pass the Symbol as function argument so  def foo(symb: Symbol) how do I make symb a Witness?

Comment: @gattaccio Instead of passing a `Symbol` you can require a `Witness[T]`.

Comment: Can't do that unfortunately - the api cannot be changed

Comment: @gattaccio Then that's going to be a problem.

Comment: @gattaccio if you're able to change the api but required to also accept `Symbol` I believe `def foo(symb: Witness.Lt[Symbol])` would work for both. There's also no longer the need to explicitly create the `Witness`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov
do I mind if I ask why 
`val sy = 'name;
repr.get(sy)`
does not create `Witness('name)`, while `'name` in 
`repr.get('name)`
creates one?